# Birthday notifications for a select group of friends on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I don't want to be notified about every friend's birthday on Facebook. There are only several birthdays that I want to be notified of. Is there any way to filter these messages somehow (e.g. by adding the friends to a list) and have it only remind me of these birthdays (via email)?

Comment: So I am guessing you do not want to use any of those shady facebook applications ;)  ?

Comment: @phwd: haha exactly

Comment: I ended up just looking at the list of all birthdays and adding the ones I wanted to my Google Calendar... not a great solution!

Comment: @x3ja: This is probably the best way to do this today.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Yahoo mail there is a way of doing this. In Yahoo Contacts you can import your Face Book Contacts. Once they are imported you will will have to go to each individual that you would like your birthday updates from and choose to "Get Updates"  They will get a request to allow you to get the updates. once this is done you will get the updaes from a group of friends into your yahoo mailbox. If you don't use yahoo then you can set up a forwarding rule to forward the updates to your Email Address.

Comment: Is it a one-time import or can it sync the contacts? Doesn't that mean that my Contacts would need to be using Yahoo so that I can get their updates? What kind of request will they be getting... is it an email?

Comment: Yes I just tried it. It sends an email invitation to the user. So the user would have to know before hand. Also you would have to set your profile picture otherwise it looks like a spam-ish email. Also the user needs to sign in to make the connection.
In addition, once the user confirms you as a Connection, you will get to share more, including birthday reminders and Contact Information updates. I have not tested if it does only birthday reminders though ,not putting the test subject through that trouble.